# Featuring Stack Exchange on YouTube - Anything I Should be Aware of?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-promotion

I am starting a YouTube channel for writing tips, and one of the first videos that I want to create is one featuring Stack Exchange. Writers Beta has really helped me in the writing field, and other sites like EL&U and Worldbuilding have also been incredibly useful. I want to share these sites with my viewers.

I'm going to open with a general Stack Exchange video, just featuring the whole collection of sites and how the general idea works. I'll focus in on specific sites in future videos. Before I do this though, I want to make sure there isn't anything I should be aware of. I have two questions:

**Is there any problem with featuring Stack Exchange on YouTube?**

**Is there any specific feature that would be really important to cover?** I go over the process of asking questions; rep, privileges, and badges; tags; and the steps involved in asking a question, including how to format and choose tags, and making sure the question is answerable. I will go into specifics (like what is on topic per site) when I feature the individual sites. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 10):

The most important thing is probably to make sure that people being directed here understand what type of question will  be received favorably and what will be hammered by down votes and closed.  Not being particularly familiar with the Writers.SE I can't give specifics, but assume you're aware of the site's standards from your rep level.

If you haven't done so, I'd suggest posting something to the local site meta as well.  Both to gauge the sentiment of other users there, and as a friendly heads up that there might be a spike in traffic from new users in the moderation queues.